# Razor Dropdownlist Unable to load the specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

Salaamun Alekum

I Was Using Drop Down List

```
@Html.DropDownList("SpecialityList", null, htmlAttributes: new { @data_toggle = "tooltip", @data_placement = "left", @title = "Select Speciality", @class = "form-control" })
```

Its Was Working Fine I Don't Know What Happened It Stop Working And Showed Me This Error

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the
>   specified metadata resource.

Comment: This seems to be entity framework issue, Restart the sql service and rebuild and run soltuion.

Comment: The Issue Was Resolved By Creating Content Of Previous Project To Newly Created Project Some Dll Files Became Corrupt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue Was Resolved By Creating Content Of Previous Project To Newly Created Project
Some Dll Files Became Corrupt

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.DropDownList("SpecialityList", new selectList(new[]{}), htmlAttributes: new { @data_toggle = "tooltip", @data_placement = "left", @title = "Select Speciality", @class = "form-control" })
```

try new selectList()